# Ruby / Rails: convert int to time OR get time from integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

We can do this:

```
i = Time.now.to_i
```

for example current:

```
i = 1274335854
```

can I convert i back to time?

Answer (score 357, accepted):

Use [Time.at](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000251):

```
t = Time.at(i)
```

Answer (score 35):

> [`time.to_i => int`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000257): Returns the value of *time* as an integer number of seconds since epoch.
>
> [`Time.at(seconds[, microseconds]) => time:`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000251) Creates a new time object with the given number of seconds (and optional microseconds) from epoch.

#### API links

- [ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html)