# Parsing date like 1240915075

Tags: ruby, parsing, date

I am learning programming and I choose Ruby as the first language to learn.

I am parsing an XML where dates are in this form: 1240915075 1224855068

How is this format called? How to use that value in a Date or Time object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is UNIX time (sometimes called Epoch time).  It measures the number of seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 (The Unix epoch is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970)

Here's an example converter: http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm

A stackoverflow question regarding converting integer time using Ruby: [Ruby / Rails: convert int to time OR get time from integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871402/ruby-convert-int-to-time)

use the Time.at function to convert e.g.:

```
t = Time.at(i)
```

Comment: Nitpick: I'd call 1 Jan 1970 epoch time. This is called a unix timestamp.

Comment: good point - updated for accuracy.  I've kind of got into the habit of calling it EPOCH time...

Answer (score 9):

That's Epoch Time (the first one corresponds to Tue Apr 28 2009 11:37:55 GMT+0100).

You can get a datetime out of it, using [`Time.at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000334), like this:

```
Time.at(1240915075)
```

Answer (score 4):

That is a unix timestamp - the number of seconds since jan 1st 1970.

An example of how to use it in Ruby is here:

```
t = Time.at(1215163257)
puts t.to_date
>> 2008-07-04
```

Comment: You should include a copy of the code in your answer. That link might change / die in the future.