# Rails convert UNIX time from Stripe created to Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to convert a time UNIX to normal time.

If I do this:

```
            <%= current_account.subscription.latest_payment.created %>
```

I get the time in UNIX as 1609022235

Then I try to convert it to normal time like this:

```
            <%= current_account.subscription.latest_payment.created.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %>
```

But I get this error:

```
undefined method `strftime' for 1609022235:Integer
```

How can I convert the time I get from Stripe in UNIX to a normal time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby / Rails: convert int to time OR get time from integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871402/ruby-rails-convert-int-to-time-or-get-time-from-integer)

Comment: when I try this I get: undefined method `time' for 1609022235:Integer

Comment: Solved, I was writing it bad. Thank you!

Comment: Can you update your question to include how you solved it, as well as the original code? It might be useful to others in future